# Does withColumn() function of spark checks every row of a Dataset or Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We generally add columns to existing spark dataframes by using withColumn function.

Just wanted to know that if we have millions of rows in a Dataset will the

```
withColumn("columnName", when(condition1, valueA).when(condition2, valueB))
```

method checks the conditions for each row of the Dataset ??

If **Yes** then is it not **poor performance** ?? & is there any better way

Comment: In my experience, withColumn given me decent performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `withColumn("columnName", column expression)` will be evaluated for each and every row, millions of them. This is a map operation so it is linearly scalable. I wouldn't worry about the performance which will depend on the complexity of the operation.

If your operation needs data from each row then you must execute it for each row.
If your operation is same per dataframe or partition of the dataframe then you can execute that operation once per dataframe or partition and write the result on each row, this can reduce some overhead.